# Undefined reference to "std::tr1::__detail::__prime_list" in G++4.8

Tags: c++

I am trying to build some code with G++4.8. Operating system is FreeBSD 9.2 64-bit.
These are the errors I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc48/include/c++/tr1/hashtable_policy.h:384: undefined reference to `std::tr1::__detail::__prime_list'
/usr/local/lib/gcc48/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:1570: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
/usr/local/lib/gcc48/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:1562: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
```

I read somewhere that those functions are in `libstdc++`. Reading this I've added that lib at my project, but I still get those errors. I should add `libstdg++` instead? Or it's something else? I don't get it.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ... with the command you use to build it.

Comment: Are you using eclipse CDT to compile this program??

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same errors when I linked the program using cc instead of gcc because of a misconfiguration of the Makefile program.